# extracting specific part from text page html python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

i have following

```
html_source = """{"linkparam":"CDAQ46598omxw=","linkmetadata":{"weblinkmetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"formfield":{"action":"CAUaMVVnd2t2Z1htRGl3OXAtS0FVaUY0QWFBQkNRLjhtZmduZEgzWXI4OG1maDFJMjRiV0gwATgAShUxMDIwMTQzMTg0NzMxMTE4NzMxNzBaGFVDQjBkMEpMbjFXY0dZY3d3Wjg3ZDJMQXAA","clientActions":[{"formaction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"11 status"}},"simpleText":"11"},"formstatus":"FORM"}}]}}
    #below  part i want to  extract from page including curly braces
    {"linkparam":"CDAQ46597omxw=","linkmetadata":{"weblinkmetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"formfield":{"action":"CAUaMVVnd2t2Z1htRGl3OXAtS0FVaUY0QWFBQkNRLjhtZmduZEgzWXI4OG1maDFJMjRiV0gwATgAShUxMDIwMTQzMTg0NzMxMTE4NzMxNzBaGFVDQjBkMEpMbjFXY0dZY3d3Wjg3ZDJMQXAA","clientActions":[{"formaction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"11 status"}},"simpleText":"11"},"formstatus":"FORM"}}]}}
    #above  part i want to  extract from page including curly braces
    {"linkparam":"CDAQ46448omxw=","linkmetadata":{"weblinkmetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"formfield":{"action":"BQkNRLjhtZmduZEgzWXI4OG1maDFJMjRiV0gwATgAShUxMDIwMTQzMTg0NzMxMTE4NzMxNzBaGFVDQjBkMEpMbjFXY0dZY3d3Wjg3ZDJMQXAA","clientActions":[{"formaction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"11 status"}},"simpleText":"11"},"formstatus":"FORM"}}]}}"""a


m = re.search(r"\{(.*?)\}", html_source)
```

i want to extract this part from the page string

```
{"linkparam":"CDAQ46597omxw=","linkmetadata":{"weblinkmetadata":{"url":"/service_ajax","sendPost":true}},"formfield":{"action":"CAUaMVVnd2t2Z1htRGl3OXAtS0FVaUY0QWFBQkNRLjhtZmduZEgzWXI4OG1maDFJMjRiV0gwATgAShUxMDIwMTQzMTg0NzMxMTE4NzMxNzBaGFVDQjBkMEpMbjFXY0dZY3d3Wjg3ZDJMQXAA","clientActions":[{"formaction":{"voteCount":{"accessibility":{"accessibilityData":{"label":"11 status"}},"simpleText":"11"},"formstatus":"FORM"}}]}}
```

Comment: And what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: read the code again i've mentioned i want to extract that specific part from page html_source

Comment: works for me. Ensure to add three double quotes (i.e. """) at the end of your first line, otherwise you get an EOF error... You can also use re.findall(...)

Comment: i want to extract specific part from the given string and i have also mentioned what part i want to extract , my string has three parts each of them is sepretated by curly braces and i want to extract that 2nd part you can see i have mentioned in string what part i want to extract sorry for my bad english :( help me

Comment: So, what part of your solution doesn't work ?

Comment: Try `\{("linkparam":"CDAQ46597o.*)\}`

Comment: doesnt work , and also linkparam is just sample its value change everytime when page refreshes

Comment: @elrichbachman - If something changes every time, and there is no other constant text, count, nor delimiter, then why post a question that has no solution ?  _off topic_.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your data looks like a list of [json](https://www.json.org) items delimited by comments (line starting by “#”).

So, you can replace the comment by a “,” and wrap your data by “[“ and “]” to create a json list.

```
import re

html_source = re.sub(r'#.*?\n', ',', html_source, flags=re.DOTALL)
html_source = '['+html_source+']'
```

Then, you can use the [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) library to parse this list of items and extract the second one:

```
import json
import pprint

data = json.loads(html_source)
pprint.pprint(data[2])
```

You get:

```
{'formfield': {'action': 'BQkNRLjhtZmduZEgzWXI4OG1maDFJMjRiV0gwATgAShUxMDIwMTQzMTg0NzMxMTE4NzMxNzBaGFVDQjBkMEpMbjFXY0dZY3d3Wjg3ZDJMQXAA',
               'clientActions': [{'formaction': {'formstatus': 'FORM',
                                                 'voteCount': {'accessibility': {'accessibilityData': {'label': '11 '
                                                                                                                'status'}},
                                                               'simpleText': '11'}}}]},
 'linkmetadata': {'weblinkmetadata': {'sendPost': True,
                                      'url': '/service_ajax'}},
 'linkparam': 'CDAQ46448omxw='}
```

**If you don’t have comments…**

You can do:

```
# insert ',' as a delimiter
html_source = html_source.replace('{"linkparam"', ', {"linkparame"')
# drop first comma
html_source = html_source[2:]
html_source = '[' + html_source + ']'
```

Comment: i added comment in string to explain what data exactly i want to extract , in my code there's no comment

Comment: If you don’t have comments you need another way to delimit the items. See my edit